Using var on request.security in pinescript
I want to hold the result of 'request.security' in a variable once so I can refer it later, but when I'm checking the result in my sample code below I get the correct result only when the timeframe of chart is daily.
When I make it 4h or even weekly I get 'NAN' result. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay=true)

var pdd = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, calc_bars_count = 2)

label.new(bar_index, high, str.format("{0, number, #.########}", pdd))


https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/concepts/other-timeframes-and-data/#gaps

try without calc_bars_count

@Gu5tavo71 I know it works if I remove calc_bars_count but I want the reason why I get Nan when I set it to 2.

add timeframe = "" to your indicator this may help you.
if you don't understand what I said paste this instead of your indicator
indicator("Test", overlay=true, timeframe = "")


I get this error: Cannot include a 'timeframe' argument in the indicator() function when the code produces side effects (e.g., the outputs of functions that create drawings or alerts). Scripts cannot evaluate side effects in other contexts.
